# Up button in toolbar points right

Tags: android, toolbar, up-button

I need to have an arrow "back" button on the left side of the toolbar,
and for some reason it points right instead of left.

How can I set it to the opposite direction?

This is my code:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.machine_tool_bar);        
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT**:
my device language is right-to-left.
I tries to set layoutDirection LTR but it didn't help..

Comment: Have you set up the Parent/child attributes in the manifest: Child activity - <activity
            android:name=".ChildActivity" android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivity">

Comment: I set the parent attribute:

<activity
            android:name=".Activities.MachineActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_machine"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".Activities.BuildingActivity">
        </activity>

but what is child attribute?

Comment: Are you using AppCompatActivity as the parent?

Comment: I'm using ActionBarActivity. Should it be replaced?

Comment: I replaced it.. it didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 6):

Maayan,

The reason that the back button is pointing to the right is that in RTL locales the drawable is taken 
from the drawable-ldrtl folder, found in the support library.

The approach I found most useful is overriding the drawable of the arrow button.

First, you need to take the arrow that is pointing left. 
It can be easily obtained from Google's Material design icons:
[Material Design Icons - Back Arrow](https://www.google.com/design/icons/#ic_arrow_back/)

Now, there are two ways that you can handle this:

1. Use mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(int resId) as follows:

> ```
> mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.machine_tool_bar);  
> mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.left_pointing_arrow);
> ```

2. If you don't want to use setNavigationIcon in the code, you can
   simply override the resource in the drawable folders. The back arrow
   is found in the support library AppCompat-v7: 
   /extras/android/support/appcompat-v7/appcompat-v7-{version}

   The resource name of the drawable you are looking for is:
   **abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha**

   You can simply copy the corresponding libraries from the support
   library to your resources folder,  and override the assets with the
   drawable that you downloaded.

   [image]

   Note that this works only from API-17 (where RTL support was
   introduced), as the folders contain the 'ldrtl' attribute.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There is a gap. light/dark Toolbar... you can have different on different views :-/